# Run A Function On All CPU Cores In Python? (Multithreading)

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a simple function to just count the amount of a certain letter there is in a string. I have a very large string, and ideally want to make the length even bigger. I have 4 CPU cores, and would like to utilize all of them. How is this possible in python 2? I would like this to be *sort of* simple... I am not a professional at this! If there is no simple way, though, I just need a good explanation! Thanks!

I have tried a couple libraries (multithreading, threading, et cetera) and couldn't seem to get them to work. I know I did something wrong, but I couldn't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem!

Use JobLib, and do something such as the following:
`print str(sum(Parallel(n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count())(delayed(function to run)(j) for The list of arguments for each process)) / 4)`

You will need to install it via pip:
`pip install joblib`

And for a very efficient function, give it an argument as to what thread it is running on so it knows what part of the workload it must take.

#### Edit

Here's a link https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html